# Mass assign attributes and save records in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Google Calendar Integration and I need ti update all the Google Calendar Events in my own database when a user refreshes their calendar.

I want to assign the `start` and `end` attribute and then save all the events at the same time.

The relationship is:

```
User has_many CalendarEvents
```

My method is:

```
def handle_calendar_update(cal_events)
  cal_events.items.each do |e|
    next if e.try(:end).nil? || e.try(:start).nil?

    params = persistable_params(e)
    google_event = user.calendar_events.where(google_id: params[:google_id])
    if google_event.empty?
      create_google_event(params)
    else
      event = google_event.first
      @current_google_events.delete(event.id)

      #THIS IS WHERE I UPDATE EXISTING RECORD
      update_google_event(event, params)
    end
  end
  user.save!
end

def update_google_event(google_event, params)
  google_event.assign_attributes(start: params[:start], end: params[:end])
end
```

But the above doesn't save the records. It works if I replace `assign_attributes` with `update` but I don't want to hit the database to save every calendar event individually.

Is there a way I can mass update the values and commit them at the same time?

Comment: a single sql `UPDATE` is not possible because you're updating different `google_events` with different values. The only thing that comes to my mind is to wrap your code in an `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do` block which will wrap all your updates in a `begin/commit` statement.

Comment: I've used [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) with `on_duplicate_key_ignore`.With the built in Rails methods it's not otherwise possible unless you manually construct the SQL.